# Create a pyramid of integers in python using nested for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

Define a function named print_pyramid(number_of_rows) which takes an integer as a parameter and prints a specific pyramid pattern using numbers. Note: you may assume that the number of rows will always be > 1 and < 10 and you must use a nested for loop.

For example:

[Pyramid I'm meant to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdCZT.png)

Above is my question and what I need to get, but I am unsure on how to complete it below is my code attempt and my result.
This is my code:

```
def print_pyramid(number_of_rows):
    
    for row in range(number_of_rows):
        
        for column in range(row, number_of_rows):
            print("", end="")
            
        for column in range(row+1):
            print(row+1, end="")
        
        for column in range(row, number_of_rows-1):
            print(" ", end= "")
            
        for column in range(row+1):
            print(row+1, end="")
        
        print()
```

But my code gives me this:
[My result/output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzkvQ.png)

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; your posting must be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: Your first `for` loop prints empty strings instead of spaces.
I believe this should be closed as a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jared's answer is correct and definitely more elegant, but here's another solution anyway. More beginner friendly hopefully easier to understand at a glance.

```
def pyramid(number_of_rows):
    for i in range(1, number_of_rows + 1):
        indent = ' ' * (number_of_rows - i)
        row = str(i) * (i * 2 - 1)
        print(indent + row)
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a list comprehension that uses a for loop to generate the pyramid pattern

```
print_pyramid = lambda x : print("\n".join([(" "*(x-i))+(str(i)*(i*2-1))+(" "*(x-i)) for i in range(1,x+1)]))
```

`print_pyramid(9)` gives:

```
        1        
       222       
      33333      
     4444444     
    555555555    
   66666666666   
  7777777777777  
 888888888888888 
99999999999999999
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function to print your pyramid in this way

```
def pyramid(rows: int) -> str:
    if rows < 1 or rows > 9:
        raise ValueError

    pyramid_string = ""

    for i in range(1, rows + 1):
        pyramid_string += f" " * (rows - i) + f"{i}" * (i * 2 - 1) + "\n"

    return pyramid_string
```

then call the function

```
print(pyramid(rows=5))
```

or you can use a variable to store the result of the function

```
five_rows_pyramid = pyramid(rows=5)
print(five_rows_pyramid)
```

**output**

```
    1
   222
  33333
 4444444
555555555
```